# Monitor always starts zoomed in a little

Tags: 18.04, display, 20.04

Whenever I boot up, my monitor's settings are always zoomed in about at 10, out of a scale of 0-100.

It also happens if I turn my monitor off and on again.

If I change my Display settings to rotate my screen orientation from Landscape to Portrait and back, but not Landscape to Flipped Landscape and back.

And changing the Scale in the Display Settings menu doesn't mess up the Zoom again, either.

I have a Dell SP2208WFP, and my Monitors.xml looks like:

```
<monitors version="2">
  <configuration>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>0</scale>
      <primary>yes</primary>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>HDMI-A-1</connector>
          <vendor>DEL</vendor>
          <product>SP2208WFP</product>
          <serial>RR268831CT0U</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>1680</width>
          <height>1050</height>
          <rate>59.954250335693359</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
  </configuration>
</monitors>
```

...

And now, Scale is reset to 1... Because I exited a fullscreen app or something??

...

It even happens in Recovery Mode, when I don't have a DISPLAY variable set.

...

But, it doesn't seem to happen if I connect through the screwy connection cables instead of HDMI...

Comment: Have you tried to reset the monitor to factory defaults? Just in case.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani - Tried factory reset while in use. Resulted in Zoom 10.

Comment: I would turn the computer off, reset the monitor and turn the computer on again.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani - Can't. It's settings don't seem to appear without a connected computer.